# the difference between provisioner kubernetes.io/cinder from openstack.org/standalone-cinder

Tags: kubernetes, storage-class-specifier

there are two kinds of provisioner in kubernetes storageclass
one is：

> kind: StorageClass
>   apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
>   metadata:
>     name: hdd1
>   provisioner: kubernetes.io/cinder
>   parameters:
>     type: HDD1 # change for your cloud volume type
>     availability: nova

and one is :

> kind: StorageClass
>   apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
>   metadata:
>     name: cinder-standard-iops
>   provisioner: openstack.org/standalone-cinder
>   parameters:
>     type: standard-iops

I'm wondering what's the difference between them,Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`provisioner: kubernetes.io/cinder` default driver is described in [official documentation.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#openstack-cinder)

`provisioner: openstack.org/standalone-cinder` : a beta feature which was created for use with external Cinder storage.

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/issues/317) you can find the main discussion about adding additional provisioner toCinder-standalone.

> The builtin kubernetes cinder support expects that nodes are deployed on nova instances. In order to use cinder as a standalone storage service I'd like to add an external provisioner. This provisioner creates volumes in cinder and retrieves connection information. It then translates this connection information into a native k8s PV (ie. iscsi or rbd are already implemented).